# Is it legal to pronounce the "t" as a glottal stop in the following words? Do British people do it?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, glottal-stop

**Are there British English native speakers who glottalise their "t"s in the following words?**

**Into, its, after, still, student**

The first case seems strange to me probably because "into" is like "in + to" and when a "t" starts a word, it never gets glottalised?

The "its" case seems strange to me, but I'm not sure why. Maybe because "ts" is pronounced like a single sound?

The last three seem like a rule: "ft", "st", "nt" never give in to glottalisation. But I made this rule up, I didn't find any rule like this online.

Comment: There are no **legal** restrictions on how people pronounce British English. Having said that, I don't think anybody glottalises their /t/ after a fricative (-ft-, st-), but yes, some people do after a liquid ('-nt'). I don't think the final /t/ of "student" is glottalised - it may be unreleased, which isn't the same thing. But the /t/ of "into" certainly can be glottalised in some accents, though I wouldn't myself.

Comment: As far as I know, a "t" is never glottalized in the *onset* of a syllable, only the coda. Have you searched for it? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization) has an article about it

Comment: @ColinFine: Would it be fair to say that *most* glottal stop usages occur because it's "easier" to move the ***back*** of the tongue ***slightly up*** rather than push the ***tip*** of the tongue ***all the way forward*** to the dental palate? I use glottal stops a *lot*, but I can't easily imagine myself using one in ***into*** unless my speech was somehow being restricted by external factors. If I couldn't be bothered to fully articulate ***into***, I think I'd just say ***inner***, rather than make all the complicated moves required to produce ***inʔə***.

Comment: (The tongue being *already* pushed up and forward in ***into*** because of the ***n***, making it easy to continue with ***t***, but much more awkward to go straight from that to a glottal stop.)

Comment: I don't know how to look for an example, but I'm pretty sure that in some English accents (I'm thinking London, or Essex), words like 'county' have a glottal realisation of /t/.

Comment: Native Yorkshire, *into* & *student* are definitely candidates for a glottal stop [as is *glottal* itself;) the others wouldn't be. The way this is easier for *into* is that you don't separate the tongue move only at the front, you lift the entire tongue, making it just as easy to complete the rear closing as to push forward to make a *t*. I'd take a guess that even a native would split this 50/50 without knowing why. We don't do it all the time, but we do do it. [I'd never say *inner* at all. This is probably a regional variation, idk where @FumbleFingers accent originates]

Comment: @gonefishin'again: I'm south of London - Cockney as was, now called "Estuary English". But apparently I easily pick up regionalisms from other areas if I spend much time with people who speak differently (often without being consciously aware that my enunciation, syntax, and/or vocabulary has shifted).

Comment: Ah, OK. *Sarf* of the River;) I'm 10 miles *Nawf* of it, these days, & have picked up all sorts of accidental 'additions' to my accent from Geordie to 'Mockney' over the past 30 years since I left the North proper. I often find that within 10 minutes of meeting me, people often start to imitate my accent back at me… it's like they don't know they're doing it half of the time. It's often amusing, but i do tend to get a lot of variants on "Ey up Lad. Də yə wurk dahn't't pit? "… usually *without* managing to get one single glottal stop correct ;)

Comment: @gonefishin'again: I have a bit of a reputation for my accent changing noticeably if I just spend an evening down the pub with someone from a different region! Curiously, though, my father - who only died a few years ago in his mid-90s - steadfastly retained his broad Lancashire accent for 70 years. He was demobbed *darn sarf*, met & married my mother in Sussex, and had only a few brief visits back to his original homeland, but his accent never noticeably shifted.

Comment: Isn't the glottalized "t" most prevalent when there are vowels on either side of it?